# Monty Hall Game: How to print which door the computer opened

Tags: c, loops, random, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    static int games = 0;
    static int stayWins = 0;
    static int switchWins = 0;
    int chosenDoor;
    int remainingDoor;
    int revealedDoor;
    int winningDoor;
    int option;

    printf("Type 0 to stop choosing and print results:  ");

    srand (time(NULL));
    do
    {
    printf("Choose door 1, 2, or 3:  ");
    scanf("%d",&chosenDoor);

    if (chosenDoor==0)
        break;

    printf("Enter '1' for stay; Enter '2' for switch:");
    scanf("%d",&option);

    winningDoor = rand() % 3 + 1;
        do
        {
            revealedDoor = rand() % 3 + 1;
        } while (revealedDoor == chosenDoor || revealedDoor == winningDoor);

        do
        {
            remainingDoor = rand() % 3+1;
        } while (remainingDoor == chosenDoor || remainingDoor == revealedDoor);

        option = rand() % 2 + 1;
        if (option == 1)
        {
            if (chosenDoor == winningDoor)
            {
                printf("You win.\n");
                stayWins++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You lose.\n");
            }
        }
        if (option == 2)
        {
            chosenDoor = remainingDoor;
            if (chosenDoor == winningDoor)
            {
                printf("You win.\n");
                switchWins++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You lose.\n");
            }
        }
        games++;
    } while (chosenDoor!=0);

printf("Out of %d games, the contestant won %d times by staying with his/her original choice and won %d times by switching his/her choice.",games,stayWins,switchWins);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a code that runs the Monty Hall game, where a user chooses a door out of three doors. One door has a prize, the other two are false. The user chooses door 1, 2, or 3 AND chooses whether to switch doors when the program opens one of the false doors.

How can I make the program open a door, where this door must be one behind which there is no prize and which is not picked by the user **AND** print its decision.

Here is what IS printed:

```
...
Choose door (1,2,3): 
Enter 1 for stay; 2 for switch: 
You win/lose.
...
```

Here is what I WANT to print:

```
...
Choose door (1,2,3): 
Door X has been opened to reveal a false door.
Enter 1 for stay; 2 for switch: 
You win/lose.
...
```

I appreciate all your help. Thank you and cheers!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Comment: Yea, I misspelled the name of the game. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick a random door and either increment or decrement the door number if the door is either the chosen door and/or the prize door.

To increment to the next door in 1,2,3,1,2,3,... order:

```
door = door%3 + 1;
```

To decrement:

```
door = (door + 1)%3 + 1;
```

...or just increment twice.